# For and Foreach Loop Container in SSIS

Tags: ssis

What are differences and similarities between **FOR** and **FOR EACH Loop** containers in **SQL Server Integration Services**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137728.aspx).

**For Loop Container**

> The For Loop container defines a repeating control flow in a package.
>   The loop implementation is similar to the For looping structure in
>   programming languages. In each repeat of the loop, the For Loop
>   container evaluates an expression and repeats its workflow until the
>   expression evaluates to False.

**Foreach Loop Container**

> The Foreach Loop container defines a repeating control flow in a
>   package. The loop implementation is similar to Foreach looping
>   structure in programming languages. In a package, looping is enabled
>   by using a Foreach enumerator. The Foreach Loop container repeats the
>   control flow for each member of a specified enumerator.

In short, a *For Loop Container* uses a loop condition that is defined by expressions whereas *Foreach Loop Container* iterates through a collection of objects.

With a *Foreach Loop Container*, you can perform variable mapping as well, which would be useful for tasks within the loop.

Comment: For similarities, it's pretty self explanatory. Hope this helps.